# sjPlot interaction plot_model. How to plot between major grid lines, edit graph for visual appeal

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, predict, sjplot

I am trying to plot predicted values for model containing an interaction. I would like to move the position of the x-axis values (factors) closer to the centre of the graph. Currently using sjPlot, `plot_model()` function and I have tried using `grid.breaks=` but this only works for numeric values. Furthermore, everything I try, the values seem to only plot along the major grid lines. Is there not a way to plot between major grid lines? Alternatively is there a way to do this in ggplot2? 
TIA

```
library("sjPlot")
data("mtcars")
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars <- subset(mtcars,!gear=="3")
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)
levels(mtcars$gear)
m_gear <- lm(mpg ~ gear*wt, data = mtcars)
plot_model(m_gear, type = "int", grid.breaks = 0.5)
```

[graph output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5VsY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use coord_cartesian. When you have factors, they are encoded as 1,2 on the x-axis, so setting the limits beyond that will give you what you need, see:

```
plot_model(m_gear, type = "int") + coord_cartesian(expand = TRUE,xlim=c(0,3))
```

[image]

```
plot_model(m_gear, type = "int") + coord_cartesian(expand = TRUE,xlim=c(0.5,2.5))
```

[image]